# Python: How to keep single quotes in list/json

Tags: python, json, curl

I am creating a rest api in Python using flask and using curl command to test my function.

Curl Command:

```
$ curl -X POST 
  -H "Content-Type:application/json"
  -d '{"keyword": "2''binders", "country": "xyz", "frequency": "1","url":"www.example.com"}' \
  http://127.0.0.1:5000/google
```

Output:

```
'['New Request', u'**2binders**', u'xyz', u'www.example.com', u'1']'
```

As you can see I am passing inches in json `2''binders` but in my list it is removing that.

## Edit:

Python:

`json = request.get_json(force=True)
print json`

Comment: Have you tried escaping them: `\"`?

Comment: I tried that, its not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!!!

curl -X POST -d '{"keyword": "2'\'''\''binders", "country": "xyz", "frequency": "1","url":"http://www.example.com/"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/google -H "Content-Type:application/json"

Answer (score 1):

In your curl command, try using `"keyword": "2\'\'binders"`. You need to escape the single quotes inside the `-d` parameter, because you're using single quotes around the `-d` parameter.

The shell is getting confused and thinking you are wanting string concatenation. E.g. the shell is seeing `'abc''def'` and interpreting that as `'abcdef'`.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for reply....I tried that it is giving me prompt(>) and not getting executed....

Comment: That suggests that it thinks you are still within a string.  Try "keyword": "2\\'\\'binders" ?

Comment: Nope now it is giving output as {"url": "http://www.example.com/", "country": "xyz", "frequency": "1", "keyword": "2\\\binders"}

Comment: My whole world is coming crashing down! I can't it to work now either!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to `json.dumps` the dictionary itself:

```
>>> s = json.dumps(d)
>>> 
>>> s
'{"url": "www.example.com", "country": "xyz", "frequency": "1", "keyword": "2\'\'binders"}'
                                                                              ^ ^
```

You will see that it will automatically escape `'`, as mentioned in the previous answer, escaping it should do the trick to you:

```
>>> json.loads(s)
{u'url': u'www.example.com', u'country': u'xyz', u'frequency': u'1', u'keyword': u"2''binders"} #Single quote is back
```

Comment: I got your point but while receiving at flask I am using 
json = request.get_json(force=True)
print json
how to convert this into the format you mention.